# regex to find elements contain a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

How to find an element contains a string? by regex.
for example, i want to find elements contains `string`:

```
<div class="a"><span id="d">string</span></div>
<span style="color: red;">string</span>
<p class="c">string</p>
```

it should return: `<span id="d">string</span>`, `<span style="color: red;">string</span>`, `<p class="c">string</p>`.

thanks.

Comment: Why with regexes? Doesn't PHP have an HTML parser implementation?

Comment: Why exclude <div></div>, is the only exception or there are more?

Comment: @D.D.C: it's an example, my `div` has some other elements. and i want to find (and remove) which one contains `string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The almost closest:

```
<([^ >]+)[^>]*>string</\1>
```

But it can fail on several badly formatted examples. And you should read [one of the best answers on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/11621).

HTH